# How to stop swipe Fliverview Iteam in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I am working with windows phone 8.1[RT] application , I want to use FlipView contains two stackPanel

```
 <FlipView x:Name="myFlip">

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk1" Checked="chk1_Checked" Unchecked="chk1_Unchecked" />
            <CheckBox x:Name="chk2" Checked="chk2_Checked" Unchecked="chk2_Unchecked" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

            <Button Click="ok" />
        </StackPanel>


    </FlipView>
```

I want that after checking chk1 and chk2 , user can swipe to other stackPanel .
And on stackPanel 2 ok button click can goBack to stackPanel 1 . 
Is that possible in flipview ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in chk1_Checked and chk1_Checked add:

```
if (chk1.IsChecked && chk2.IsChecked)
{
   myFlip.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

in ok add:

```
myFlip.SelectedIndex = 0;
```